# tableLayout strechcolumns doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a TablLayout, it has 1 row and 2 columns.

The first column is a text, and I want it as big as possible, the second one is another table with 2 rows and 1 column:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"

    >
<TableRow>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parkingDataText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
            />
    <TableLayout>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonStar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:background="@null" 
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonRent" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:background="@null" 
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</TableRow>
```

I thought I had to use strechColumns="1" and the first column occupied the space that the second one doesnt use, but it doesn't work. 
Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ups! strechColums="1" means the second one! the first one is "0".

thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try below layout for your requirement :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="2">
<TableRow>
   <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Save As..."
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_width="200dp" />
        <TableLayout 
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="2">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Textview column1"
            android:padding="3dip" />

    </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Textview column2"
            android:padding="3dip" />

    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout> 
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```